# Syntax error/ for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am having a problem with the simplest code, im sure its something stupid. When i put a ';' after the main function, it says something along the lines of old style formatting listing. So when i remove it, it says there is a ';' missing before ')'. Any help would be appreciated, the code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

int i;

for (i = 0, i < 10, i++)
    cout << i << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

this is all in visual studio express by the way, also putting {} for the for loop makes no difference to the outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `';'` when separating elements of the for statement.

```
for (i = 0 ; i< 10; i++)
```

Comment: thanks everyone, such a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << i << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the basic for-loop syntax

> for (*init*; *condition*; *increment*)
>   statement_or_statement_block;

You should use `';'` instead of `','`

```
 for (i = 0;i < 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

put ';' instead of ','  
    `for( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Eric Fortin's reply is correct. Also, if more than one line of code comes after the for statement and is included in the for loop you will need to use curly braces

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    some code;
    some code;
}
```